# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity when add customize UserRole get cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

i use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework and need to customize Identity classes property.

i have Context like :

```
 public class GSSDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AppRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim> 
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        private static GSSDbContext _context;

        static GSSDbContext()
        {
#if DEBUG
            ConnectionString = "GssConnection";
#endif
        }
}
```

and my Identity Classes are :

```
 public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser 
    {
        public int Loc_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Loc_Id")]
    
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
       
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
       }
 public class AppRole : IdentityRole
    
    {
        public string PersianName { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

everything is fine, until i add  custom class for IdentityUserRole and change my code  like :

```
public class GSSDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AppRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, AppUserRole, IdentityUserClaim> 
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        private static GSSDbContext _context;

        static GSSDbContext()
        {
#if DEBUG
            ConnectionString = "GssConnection";
#endif
        }
}
}

public class AppUserRole : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole
    {
       
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

and got error :

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error   CS0311  The type cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>'. There is no implicit reference

[image]

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

changed code to :
Context :

```
public class GSSDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AppRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, AppUserRole, IdentityUserClaim> 
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        private static GSSDbContext _context;

        static GSSDbContext()
        {
#if DEBUG
            ConnectionString = "GssConnection";
#endif
        }
}
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, AppUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
AppRole : IdentityRole<string, AppUserRole>{}

public class AppRole : IdentityRole<string, AppUserRole>{}
```

and problem solved.
actually, I have to define my new IdentityUserRole (name: appUserRole)
for my user and role classes. the key was :

> IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, AppUserRole,
> IdentityUserClaim>